# alternative to wiring servlet body

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am very new to java programming. I have given with a scenario and since I do not have deep technological knowledge I have some difficulties with this task.

When I do web programming using `HTML/PHP`, once `HTML` form page action would be the `PHP` page. `PHP` page will do the server side processing (**insert data to DB**) and the directed to the next appropriate page.

When comes to `JSP` I have the difficulty with doing this.
How to **do server side processing using JSP and Servlet**. If I use the `servlet` as action page, the next page to be appear after the processing how to call it. Do I have to write each HTML code inside the `servlet`?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to write each HTML code inside the servlet?

The answer is NO in java web world. You write HTML code in JSP. You need to study MVC model in Java servlet. Here is the link: http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm. This is very basic MVC application using Servlet(Controller), View ( JSP/JSTL) and Model ( Your java POJO beans that contains data ). You can study any web framework like Spring MVC, Struts but I am not recommending you since you are new to java web.

Comment: got the idea. thank you very much. thanks for he link provided